# To make it mandatory for user to upload document when changing a dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a requirement from Business. Document upload is to be mandatory when changing a dropdown.

Following solutions, we have tried:

if(data.status == 'Completed' && (data.actions == "start" || data.actions == "continue" || data.actions == "work in progress"|| data.actions == "analysis")&& (this.state.fileFromAPI == '' )
) {
this.setState({
isToastOpen: true,
toastMessage: 'File mandatory when updating status to completed',
messageType: 'critical'
});
}

This solution just checks if any document is uploaded or not when the dropdown status is updated. **Requirement is dropdown status can be updated only if we upload a new document and can ignore previously uploaded documents.**

Is it possible to achieve this requirement using Reactjs? Can anyone please help with this?